# Force-load JS into AJAX loaded HTML file

Tags: jquery, ajax

EDIT: shorter version of the question

I load an .html file through AJAX:

```
         $(".btn_quizTEST").click(function (event) {     
         $.ajax({
     url:"/working/ajaxtestFillinBlank1.html", 
     cache: false,
     dataType: "html",
     success:function(result){
          $(".exspace").html(result);
        }});  
    });
```

and my .js file is not working within the loaded file ( guess because JS is already loaded and doesn't see the HTML that's not yet loaded through AJAX)

How do I apply a JS file to a loaded AJAX html file?

Is there something like:

```
         $.ajax({
load a file
}).load( load JS file after loading the HTML file );
```

Comment: Is your javascript expecting a $(document).ready() event?

Comment: Never mind, I finally figured it out :) ---> $.ajax({ load file}).load('path to .js');

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out :

```
  $("button").click(function (event) {
     $.ajax({
                    url: // file URL,
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#DIV').append(result);
                    }
                }).load('jsfile.js');  <-- load JS file after click event
 });
```